# Perl Expat.xs.dll error when running importxml.pl for Bugzilla installation

Tags: xml, perl, bugzilla

The organization where I work uses a Bugzilla installation for issue resolution and tracking. We're doing a big upgrade jump from Bugzilla 3.2.3 to 5.0.1. Everything was going well until I tried using the importxml.pl script in Bugzilla to import bugs from an XML file output from the old installation.

I have Strawberry Perl (5.22.0) installed. The database (in case it matters) is Oracle 11g, and the application is running on a Windows 2012 R2 VM.

Whenever I try to run the script, I get the following error:

> Can't load 'C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/auto/XML/Parser/Expat/Expat.xs.dll' for module XML::Parser::Expat: load_file:The specified module could not be found at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 193.
>
> at C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/XML/Parser.pm line 18.
>
> Compilation failed in require at C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/XML/Parser.pm line 18.
>
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/XML/Parser.pm line 22.
>
> Compilation failed in require at C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/XML/Twig.pm line 149.
>
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/XML/Twig.pm line 149.
>
> Compilation failed in require at importxml.pl line 77.
>
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at importxml.pl line 77.

I've been hunting for answers all day and come across numerous ones that have not helped:

1) Setting the IIS Application Pool "Load User Profile" to "True."

2) Copied libexpat-1__.dll from C:\Strawberry\c\bin to C:\Strawberry\perl\bin.

3) Used CPAN Client to install XML::Parser and XML::Parser::Expat. Both of these reported as being up-to-date and did not install further modules.

4) Verified my PATH variables. Currently, the following paths are included:

> C:\Strawberry\c\bin
>
> C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin
>
> C:\Strawberry\perl\bin
>
> C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\bin

5) Gave "Everyone" full control of the \Bugzilla and \Strawberry folders. This didn't help, so I revoked those privileges for security's sake.

6) Beat my head against the desk. This helped my stress, but not the situation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Re (3), that's just a version check. Doesn't even load the module.

Comment: @ikegami, do you mean that running "install XML::Parser::Expat" isn't actually trying to install it and it's just running the version check? Wouldn't it fail and tell me that my version isn't up-to-date even if that was the case?

Comment: Your version is up to date. Whether it works or not is orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but not with Bugzilla.
"set PATH=%PATH%;\c\bin" solved my problem.

Have you booted you server after installing perl?
Is "C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\bin" in the system environment variables?
You can check if your Bugzilla instance has inherited all system environment variables by means of process explorer from sysinternals suite.

Comment: I've got both the ..\c\bin and ..\vendor\bin strings in my PATH environment variable. The server's been rebooted since installing Perl (and I did it again since I've been fiddling with the PATH environment variable). Checked IIS's environment variables and it included the necessary PATH variable, but... no beans.